# Land scape issue when screen orientation off and on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Landscape mode handle when auto screen orientation is ON and easily turn to portrait. But Auto Screen Orientation is Off then forcefully change supported orientation which effect on if Auto Screen Orientation is ON. Pls tell me these things in WP

How check auto screen orientation of setting ON or Off?

Another way to change orientation of screen contents?

Answer (score 0):

To specify that your app supports portrait and landscape, you must set the [SupportedOrientations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.supportedorientations(v=vs.105).aspx) property to [PortraitOrLandscape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.supportedpageorientation(v=vs.105).aspx) either in the XAML or in the code.

Add this piece of code in your `XAML` within the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>`

```
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"
```

Take a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000529/windows-phone-change-layout-on-orientation-change)

Hope it helps!

Comment: i already use this. i need to **How check auto screen orientation of setting ON or Off?**

Comment: I don't think you can do it programmatically. Take a look over [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/45090/windows-phone-8-lock-screen-orientation-to-portrait-or-landscape/) to do it through settings in your device.

Answer (score 0):

Read this quick start tutorial on how to gracefully handel orientation change in windows phone 8

[**Screen orientation for Windows Phone 8**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

In short, if you need to support both orientations than first you need to change your `SupportedOrientation` in you page xaml `SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"`

Then handle orientation Changed Event in the code for UI related changes(as explained in above artical)

You can use following page property on page load to check the current orientation of the screen when it is loaded.

`this.SupportedOrientations`

Hope this helps

Comment: i already use in xaml and C# code. i need to **How check auto screen orientation of setting ON or Off?**

Comment: You cannot check that value in your application code. But why you need that value? in case if screen rotation mode is Off orientation changed event will not be raised!